# syntax error in Data Explorer

Tags: sql, syntax-error, dataexplorer

[The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) allows SQL queries against a Stack Exchange database. I tried this one —

```
select
  month(CreationDate) month,
  year(CreationDate) year,
  sum(lower(left(Title,2))='wh')/count(*) wh,
  (select sum(Score)/count(*)
   from Posts u
   where month(CreationDate)=month(t.CreationDate)
     and year(CreationDate)=year(t.CreationDate)
     and lower(left(Title,2))='wh'
     and PostTypeId=1 -- question
  ) wh_score,
  sum(Score)/count(*) score,
  (select sum(AnswerCount)/count(*)
   from Posts u
   where month(CreationDate)=month(t.CreationDate)
     and year(CreationDate)=year(t.CreationDate)
     and lower(left(Title,2))='wh'
     and PostTypeId=1 -- question
  ) wh_answers,
  sum(AnswerCount)/count(*) answers
from Posts t
where PostTypeId=1 -- question
group by month,year;
```

— but the site told me

> Incorrect syntax near ')'. Incorrect syntax near 'wh_score'. Incorrect syntax near 'wh_answers'.

and I cannot figure out why. Can anyone help, please?

---

Things I've tried, to no avail:

- `datepart(month,CreationDate)` instead of `month(CreationDate)` (and likewise for `year`)
- explicit `as` for aliases (then the latter two of the three errors complained about 'at' rather than about the aliases)
- aliases that aren't built-in function names
- `left(Title,2)` instead of `lower(left(Title,2))`
- putting parentheses around the first two, and around the last two, of the four things joined by `and`s
- explicit `u.` for column names in the subqueries

Comment: Followup: This is now at http://data.stackexchange.com/jewish%20life%20and%20learning/query/109122

Comment: [Followup question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086325)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't group by an alias, you need to specify the computed column
2. This is not allowed : `sum(lower(left(Title,2))='wh')`. You have to convert it into a `CASE WHEN` operator.

Here a corrected query (that gives a timeout):

```
select
    month(CreationDate) month
  , year(CreationDate) year
  , sum(case when lower(left(Title,2))='wh' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) wh
  , (select sum(Score)/count(*)
   from Posts u
   where month(CreationDate)=month(t.CreationDate)
     and year(CreationDate)=year(t.CreationDate)
     and lower(left(Title,2))='wh'
     and PostTypeId=1 -- question
  ) wh_score,
  sum(Score)/count(*) score,
  (select sum(AnswerCount)/count(*)
   from Posts u
   where month(CreationDate)=month(t.CreationDate)
     and year(CreationDate)=year(t.CreationDate)
     and lower(left(Title,2))='wh'
     and PostTypeId=1 -- question
  ) wh_answers,
  sum(AnswerCount)/count(*) answers
from Posts t
where PostTypeId=1 -- question
group by month(CreationDate), year(CreationDate);
```

What are you trying to do with this query?

Comment: Thank you! +1. It works now. (And doesn't timeout for me, but I'm doing it for a small SE site.) But it treats (or, at least, displays) every column in the result as an integer, so `wh` comes through (of course) as always `0`. Do you know any way around that? (Of course, I can ask it separately.)

Comment: Ask in a separate question. I don't understand what your are trying to do with this query, so I can't help you more.

Comment: Okay, will do. (I'm trying to determine whether `wh-` questions are 'better' than other questions: specifically, whether they have more answers or net votes.)