# Getting non-integer results in Data Explorer

Tags: sql, integer, decimal, dataexplorer

[The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) allows SQL queries against a Stack Exchange database. The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/jewish%20life%20and%20learning/query/109122) —

```
select
  month(CreationDate) month,
  year(CreationDate) year,
  sum(case when lower(left(Title,2))='wh' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) wh,
  (select sum(Score)/count(*)
   from Posts u
   where
     month(CreationDate)=month(t.CreationDate) and
     year(CreationDate)=year(t.CreationDate) and
     lower(left(Title,2))='wh' and
     PostTypeId=1 -- question
  ) wh_score,
  sum(Score)/count(*) score,
  (select sum(AnswerCount)/count(*)
   from Posts u
   where
     month(CreationDate)=month(t.CreationDate) and
     year(CreationDate)=year(t.CreationDate) and
     lower(left(Title,2))='wh' and
     PostTypeId=1 -- question
  ) wh_answers,
  sum(AnswerCount)/count(*) answers
from Posts t
where PostTypeId=1 -- question
group by month(CreationDate), year(CreationDate)
;
```

— [courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16076790) of [Scorpi0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128662/scorpi0) — yields all integer values in the results: everything gets either rounded or truncated (I don't know which). (This is especially annoying in the `wh` column, where every value is therefore `0`.) Is there a way to force decimal or values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a lot of langage, when you do 1/2, it perform the division of 1 by 2 and return the quotient, so 0 here.

```
n/m => n = m * q + r
1/2 => 1 = 2 * 0 + 1
```

Let's be pragmatic : just multiply by a decimal, like this :

```
(sum(AnswerCount) * 1.0)/count(*)
```

And you will get decimal instead of int.